# To extract data between two strings

Tags: python, json

I have a file with the following json file, I want to extract the data between transcript and explain.

`    "1010320": {

```
    "transcript": [

        "1012220", 

        "to build. so three is not correct."
    ], 

    "explain": "Describing&Interpreting" 

},
```

"1019660": {

```
    "transcript": [

      "1031920", 

        "The moment disturbance comes, if this control strategy is to be implemented properly, the moment disturbance comes, it is picked up immediately, and corrective action done immediately." 

    ], 

    "explain": "Describing&Interpreting" 
}, 

"1041600": {

   "transcript": [`
```

`"1044860",`

`"this is also not correct because it will take some time."`

`],`

`"explain": "Describing&Interpreting"`

`},`

`   "1053100": {

```
    "transcript": [ 

        "1073800", 
    ], `
```

`        "explain": "Describing&Interpreting"
    },

```
"2082920": { 

    "transcript": [ 

        "2089000", 

        "45 minutes i.e., whereas this taken around 15seconds or something. Is that ok?"
 ], 

    "explain": "Describing&Interpreting" 
}, `
```

I want to sort the string and numbers.

The output should be:

```
"to build. so three is not correct."

"The moment disturbance comes, if this control strategy is to be implemented properly, the moment disturbance comes, it is picked up immediately, and corrective action done immediately." 

"this is also not correct because it will take some time."

"45 minutes i.e., whereas this taken around 15seconds or something. Is that ok?"
```

Is it possible??

Comment: You seem to be looking for a JSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n -e '/",[[:blank:]]*$/,/^[[:blank:]]*],/ {
   /^[[:blank:]]*".*"[[:blank:]]*$/ {
      G;p
      }
   }' YourFile
```

Based on your sample structure, take string between string ending with `",` and string starting with `],`, only print line that are only between quote.
I just add the possibility of several space char ([:blank:] in fact for extend space char like tab)

Comment: Thank you.. But it is not working for me. I am not getting any output.

Comment: try with option `-r` (maybe `-e`is enough)  and `--posix`, It work on my AIX/KSH/non GNU sed and your are certainly with a GNU sed

Comment: It's done.. 

`sort filename.json  | uniq -uc`

`cat filename.json | tr -d '[]''{},''[0-9]'`

Comment: But the problem is, It is not giving the last entry.
`"45 minutes i.e., whereas this taken around 15seconds or something. Is that ok?"`

Comment: i modify the script a bit in reply.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^\s*"transcript": \[/,/^\s*\],/{/^\s*"[^"]*"\s*$/p}' file
```

This uses seds grep-like mode and prints lines which start and end in double-quotes  in the transcript clauses.

Comment: Hi, Can we do this in python??